# Trouble understanding difference-in-differences estimates

Tags: inference, econometrics, stata, difference-in-difference

I am writing with a question about understanding difference-in-differences estimates. I am using a DID approach for my Bachelor's thesis to measure the impact of TBTF reforms on SRISK of G-SIBs in the EU (the substance is not really important though, I need help with the technical part of my model), however, I have not received extensive training on DID throughout my studies so I am having trouble understanding the estimates. The model I am using is different than the introductory DID models with a post, treat, and a post*treat, so I am having trouble finding answers to my questions about it online.

This is my model:
$$
Y_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \gamma_{t} + \sum_{k=1}^{3}\beta _{k}\cdot g_{i}\cdot \tau _{kt} + \varepsilon _{it}
$$

Where Yit is the SRISK measure of bank i in quarter t, alphas and gammas are bank- and quarter-fixed effects, and gi is a dummy variable indicating where a bank is a G-SIB.

Moreover, the $\tau _{kt}$ are dummy variables with a value of 1 for the pre-crisis
period (2002-2007), the crisis period (2008-2013), and the post-Covid-19 period
(2020-2023), respectively, and 0 otherwise. The post-crisis-post-reform period (2014-2019) is
omitted and serves as a reference period.

This model is based on a paper by Ichiue et al. (2022) that conducts a similar analysis (https://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.4019583).

So, this is not an orthodox DID model in that I do not really have a pre-treatment period and a post-treatment period (though the periods are the same for all banks), but rather 4 different periods, wich each observation falling into one of them (so data is 2002-2023). This is my understanding of the model: since I omit the post-crisis-post-reform period, the interpretation of betas is the difference between G-SIBs and the control group in the extent to which SRISK changed between periods. In other words, if $\beta _{2}$ is positive and significant, it means that the SRISK was "more higher" for G-SIBs than for the control group during the crisis period compared to the post-crisis-post-reform period. So the SRISK has declined for both from the crisis period to the post-crisis-post-reform period (not information I get from a positive $\beta _{2}$, but it is the case), but it has declined more for G-SIBs.

My Question 1 is: is my interpretation of the betas correct?

The second problem with interpretation comes from the estimates. I have three different control groups, so I repeat the analysis three times. I am using Stata 17 to perform the analysis, and run the following commands three times, each time with a different control group:

```
xtreg srisk pre_crisis_gsib crisis_gsib covid_gsib, fe vce(cluster id)
xtreg srisk pre_crisis_gsib crisis_gsib covid_gsib i.quarter, fe vce(cluster id)
```

I obtain the following results (first column is without time-fixed effects, second is with):

```
------------------------------------
                 (1)          (2)   
------------------------------------
β1          -36756.2***  -29447.0***
            (5461.0)     (6176.5)   

β2           19261.2***   11527.8   
            (6807.6)     (7170.2)   

β3           12455.2**     7062.0   
            (4670.5)     (4944.9)   
------------------------------------
N               2247         2247   
vce          cluster      cluster   
r2             0.498        0.574   
------------------------------------
Standard errors in parentheses
* p<0.1, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01

------------------------------------
                 (1)          (2)   
------------------------------------
β1          -36756.2***  -32493.9***
            (5473.8)     (5849.2)   

β2           19261.2***   14386.4*  
            (6823.6)     (7263.9)   

β3           12455.2**     8736.8*  
            (4681.4)     (5061.5)   
------------------------------------
N               1906         1906   
vce          cluster      cluster   
r2             0.533        0.581   
------------------------------------
Standard errors in parentheses
* p<0.1, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01

------------------------------------
                 (1)          (2)   
------------------------------------
β1          -36756.2***  -35165.6***
            (5386.8)     (5404.1)   

β2           19261.2***   18826.9***
            (6715.0)     (6732.4)   

β3           12455.2***   11810.8** 
            (4607.0)     (4641.9)   
------------------------------------
N               6299         6299   
vce          cluster      cluster   
r2             0.537        0.552   
------------------------------------
Standard errors in parentheses
* p<0.1, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01
```

Now, the second columns make sense. From the first to the third table, the control groups represent banks that are decreasingly similar to G-SIBs in terms of size and how they were impacted by the reforms. So, looking at the second columns it the changes in betas make sense. For example, $\beta _{2}$ growing means that the SRISK of G-SIBs has declined more compared to the SRISK of the control group, and it makes sense that the results grow in significance (all this is consistent with the trends that I plotted).

What really confuses me, however, is that the estimates in the first column stay the same no matter the control group, and only SE change. If my interpretation of $\beta _{2}$ is correct, meaning that if positive, it represents the extent to which the decline in SRISK was greater for G-SIBs, it makes no sense that this "extent" is the same no matter what control group is used.

For reference, this are the visualised trends:
[image: The OLB, Above100 and Above10 are the three control groups I use in the analysis. Vertical lines represent treatment periods.]
The OLB, Above100 and Above10 are the three control groups I use in the analysis. Vertical lines represent treatment periods.

I would really appreciate any input on this. My thesis submission deadline is in a couple of days, and I have only recently added the second and third control group, so previously throughout my thesis process, I did not run into the issue of the same estimates across situations that, based on my understanding, should not produce the same estimates.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. So as those trends come closer together in the post-crisis/post-reform epoch (i.e., 2014 through 2019), the estimates become more positive?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I am not completely sure what you mean by trends coming closer together. I think I might not have been clear in my post, the first table is with the OLB control group, the second with Above100 and the third Above10. So all groups' SRISK had declined, but the decline is greatest for G-SIBs, then OLBs, Above100 and lastly Above10. When compared to increasingly dissimilar control groups thus, the difference in the decline becomes greater. But as the model omits the post-reform period, the positive estimate on the second means that it was higher before the reforms - it is reversed